# Schedule event in mysql is not working

Tags: mysql, database

```
alter event my_event
   on schedule every 1 day starts '2016-06-14 01:06:00'
do
  insert into a(test) values('sample-1');
```

It should be worked one time in every day. But it is not working.

Comment: Why don't you post the full body of `my_event` ? And have you checked whether the `event_scheduler` is `ON` OR `OFF`? Run this to test: `SELECT @@event_scheduler;`

Comment: event_scheduler is on. but it is not working @1000111. I would like to create an event in mysql which will run every  date 12:00 AM.

Comment: Please post the full code of that event.

Comment: I would like to insert data into table  'a' once in a day at 12:00 AM. For that, I wrote a event which is as follows: create event my_event
   on schedule every 1 day starts '2016-06-14 01:06:00'
do
  insert into a(test) values('sample-1');

Comment: You have to wait for the next schedule. And the next schedule is `2016-06-15 01:06:00`. (tomorrow).

Comment: Thanks @1000111. You are right.